# uniform probability distribution on the reals

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I heard that you cannot create a uniform probability distribution on the reals because it breaks the additivity axiom where the individual probabilities of a countable number of disjoint subsets of your space should equal the probability of their union.  So how would you mathematically describe an idea such as selecting a random number from the reals? Or ideas similar to this. Is there some other kind of math that you use, some other distribution or concept?

Comment: Maybe you mean something like the axiom of choice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice

Comment: It would help if you indicated what properties you'd like your random selection process to have.

Answer (score 3):

(1) How about: uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$?

(2) More generally, fix a probability distribution $\phi$ on $\mathbb R$, then use $\phi$ to specify your random numbers.  For example, use a normal distribution.

(3) Do not use a probability measure, instead use Lebesgue measure.

More philosophical answer: why would you want to choose a random real number?  Use those reasons to specify what properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a "distribution" in the strict sense, there is the notion of an [improper prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors).  This corresponds not to a specific random selection procedure, but rather to a general state of ignorance about the details of said selection procedure.